# Element value inside Bootstrap accordion doesn't validate empty

Tags: html, jquery

I have some cards dynamically generated with a loop. In one part, I have an accordion element that is triggered with a button (Bootstrap method). I change the background color of that button when the element accordion-body, which is contenteditable true, has value in it after losing focus. The problem is, I want to remove the button color if the accordion-body is empty, but the element accordion-body seems to still have a value after losing focus even when the user deletes all content.

This is the accordion code:

Why is it that $(this).val() never evaluates empty? I had a console message in the if statements, it never goes to the else validation.

```js
$('.accordion-body').on('focusout', function() {
  var style = $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('button[id=infobtn]').attr('style');

  //it will return string
  style += ';background-color: #f4cccc;';

  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('button[id=infobtn]').attr('style', style);
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('button[id=infobtn]').attr('style');
  }
});
```

```html
<script> src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="mySpan">

<div class="accordion accordion-flush py-0" id="accordionFlushExampleOne">
  <div class="accordion-item py-0">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" id="infobtn" name="infobtn" style="height:25px; <?php if (!empty($additionalInfo)) echo " background-color: #f4cccc; " ?>" type="btn btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne>" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">Additional Info
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExampleOne">
      <div class="accordion-body fw-bold" id="additionalInfo" name="additionalInfo" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo "$additionalInfo" ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi Isherwood. I fixed the brace, thank you! I believe I'm going to remove the PHP values that make the accordion work dynamically.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Don't forget to use the Tidy button.

Comment: @Fquintero Why did you delete your questions JavaScript/JQuery part now?

Comment: @bitski My bad, let me add it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the recommendations and information about this matter. @bitski suggestion took me to the right direction. I tried all the options given, and somehow my accordion-body element always received the `<br>` value, it was never empty. I did some research and found a way to reset the content after losing focus (I ended up using blur instead).

So my accordion-body field looks like this now:

```
<div class="accordion-body fw-bold" id="additionalInfo" name="additionalInfo" contenteditable="true" onblur="event.target.scroll(0,0)">
```

And my jquery looks like this:

```
$('.accordion-body').on('blur', function() {

  var style = $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('button[id=infobtn]').attr('style'); //it will return string
  style += ';background-color: #f4cccc;';

  if ($(this).text().trim().length != 0) {
      $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('button[id=infobtn]').attr('style', style);
  } else {
      style += ';background-color: #FFFFFF'; //When field is empty, change the button background color back to white
      $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('button[id=infobtn]').attr('style', style);
      }

});
```

That did the trick! Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Giving HTML **block elements** the attribute `contenteditable="true"` is responsible for that behaviour.

Removing the content of such an element in the browser, will set a replacement `<br>` instead in there.

Thus, `if ($(this).val() != '')` will never be true, because your containing element will never be empty.

Changing the containing `div` to an **inline element** such as `span` fixes the issue and your conditonal logic will get to work.

HTML - swap `<div>` with `<span>`

```
<span class="accordion-body fw-bold" id="additionalInfo" name="additionalInfo" contenteditable="true">
  <?php echo "$additionalInfo" ?>
</span>
```

HTML & JQuery - inner `<span>` within `<div>` to preserve bootstrap accordion design

```
<div class="accordion-body fw-bold" id="additionalInfo" name="additionalInfo" contenteditable="true">
  <span contenteditable="true">
    <?php echo "$additionalInfo" ?>
  </span>
</div>

$('.accordion-body span').on('focusout', function() {...
```

Comment: Thanks for the info bitski. I forgot to add a span element that wraps all content in the card. I just edit my html code to show it. I tried changing the div class to span, and it changed the accordion design. Unfortunately, it didn't work either. Is there a way to check if val() equals to a <br> tag? Just a thought.

Comment: @Fquintero I have tested it. When i swapped the div with span and then removed its content via browser, the conditional check for the content container being empty went true.

Comment: @Fquintero I now adapted my answer accordingly to peserve accordion functionality incase